# How do I get Graph API delta changes due to permissions changes?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, sharepoint-online

I have an azure AD registered application. With delegated permissions of a user with AllSites.FullControl, I'm able to get drive/root/delta in Graph API.

Problems I'm having making the delta calls as the delegated user are:

- the deltas are not consistent. Sometimes I get results back after changing the permissions of a file/folder, sometimes I don't
- Despite that I'm passing in these Prefer headers `deltashowsharingchanges, deltashowremovedasdeleted, deltatraversepermissiongaps`, I'm not getting back `@microsoft.graph.sharedChanged` in the response.

The above issues are my primary questions.

Grasping at straws here, but please let me know if I would have better luck with an app-only authentication. If so, how to get it set up with my existing Azure AD registered application, without access to Powershell or Windows (e.g. if I need to use a certificate instead of client_id/client_secret, as there is conflicting information about this, and only instructions on how to get it done with Powershell). I've already started to try to test this, but have not successfully found information on how to get this working in a multi-tenant use-case, wherein I'm trying to access the Sharepoint of an outside tenant from an Azure AD registered app-only authenticated application. All existing instructions I've seen thus far are not multi-tenant and grant themselves permissions in their own Azure AD portal.

Comment: You can use client secrets for your development purpose, but when you the production consider using certificates - it's safer and the recommended one.

Comment: Outside of your code, try repro the issue in POSTMAN/Graph Explorer with delegated/application permissions to see if its work or see the same as well. I tried the same and helped me to isolate the issue. BTW, if your use case is with regular sharepoint/onedrive then its ok; but if you're trying to fetch the info for shared ones then you might not see the delta changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that indeed, using app-only client credentials authentication was necessary to get `@microsoft.graph.sharedChanged` in the response, though this is not documented anywhere. In addition, deltas are being returned consistently now. Presumably, Microsoft is doing something to try to return only deltas relevant to the delegated user, although that is not enough in my opinion to explain for the lack of deltas in some cases. Nevertheless, I'm getting the response I need using app-only client credentials.

Regarding use of certificate -- it was not necessary if accessing my own tenant where the app is registered, but if accessing a 3rd party tenant, a certificate was required instead of client_secret.